# Windows' Time gets reset when using wubi installer?

Tags: wubi

I am new to the Linux world and I wanted to try Ubuntu - so I installed it using Wubi. Everything is working fine till now, but I noticed an strange issue:
Everytime I boot Ubuntu and later use windows the system time gets set to 11:54 of the current day.

Please could anyone tell me whats the issue?

Answer (score 0):

That's been happening a long time - not sure the exact reason but I suspect that ubiquity always assumes the computer clock is UTC and then it corrects it to local time. But if you connect your Wubi install to the internet it will pick up the correct time. Also, make sure your Windows is also connected to a time server... or, for example, you'll find like I did that whoever sets daylight savings first affects the other and get dropped back 2 hours.